# Python Dataframe prevent duplicates while concating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have two dataframes. I concat them to make one. The problem is, while troubleshooting the code, I will the same concat code multiple times. This produces the dataframe with repeated rows as many times I do the concat. I want to prevent it.

**My code:**

```
rdf = pd.DataFrame({'A':[10,20]},index=pd.date_range(start='2020-05-04 08:00:00', freq='1h', periods=2))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[30,40]},index=pd.date_range(start='2020-05-04 10:00:00', freq='1h', periods=2))

# Run it first time
rdf= pd.concat([rdf,df2])
# First time result
rdf
                      A
2020-05-04 08:00:00  10
2020-05-04 09:00:00  20
2020-05-04 10:00:00  30
2020-05-04 11:00:00  40

# Run it second time
rdf= pd.concat([rdf,df2])
# second time result produces duplicates
rdf
                      A
2020-05-04 08:00:00  10
2020-05-04 09:00:00  20
2020-05-04 10:00:00  30
2020-05-04 11:00:00  40
2020-05-04 10:00:00  30
2020-05-04 11:00:00  40
```

**My solution:** My approach is right a new line code and drop duplicates by keeping the first.

```
rdf= pd.concat([rdf,df2])
rdf.drop_duplicates(keep='first',inplace=True)
rdf
                      A
2020-05-04 08:00:00  10
2020-05-04 09:00:00  20
2020-05-04 10:00:00  30
2020-05-04 11:00:00  40
```

Is there a better approach? I mean, can we prevent this while concating? so, no need to write extra line code for dropping the duplicates.

Comment: Is there a reason you're concating df2 to the end of rdf twice? Won't this always end up with all the rows of df2 duplicated at the end of rdf?

Comment: @HenryEcker I have shown here for demo. Actually, I run the code multiple times while troubleshooting as explained in my q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then let us try `combine_first`

```
rdf = rdf.combine_first(df2)
rdf = rdf.combine_first(df2)
rdf
Out[115]: 
                        A
2020-05-04 08:00:00  10.0
2020-05-04 09:00:00  20.0
2020-05-04 10:00:00  30.0
2020-05-04 11:00:00  40.0
```

Comment: Really appreciate for introducing this. I heard `combine_first` for the first time here. Thanks a ton. How different is this with `concat`? Can we use this all the time?

Comment: @Mainland concat , is append , combine_first , is look up the index , adding the missing one from df2 to df1 ~

Comment: One more question: can I use `combine_first` all the time and just discard the `concat`?

Comment: @Mainland if you need update the existing index and update the new index, you can do combine_first, if you want to append whatever the new df have you need concat , for your case answer is yes